# Find and replace multiple different keywords in text block

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I have this block of text which should be customizable in that some of the words/keywords that can be customized. Let's say this is the block of text below.

> Dear [Name], Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,
>   sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna
>   aliquam erat volutpat on [Date]. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis
>   nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex
>   ea commodo consequat.Please contact [PhoneNumber]

The words within square brackets are the keywords that should be replaceable. The data to replace them will come from db, which is fine. What I want to know is that what is the best way to do this. Should I just search for particular keywords one by one (Many more keywords are there, but there's no guarantee which one may feature in which block of text, so I will have to check for all possible keywords for every block of text) and then replace them with the appropriate value using `str_replace`? Or, is there a better way do go about it? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

str_replace can replace a whole array in one step:

```
$map = array('[PhoneNumber]'=>'...', '[Date]'=>'...',...);


$result = str_replace(array_keys($map), array_values($map), $input);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$admin_email_text = 'This is [first-field-label] the test, you can send the email at [form-email]';
        $admin_email_text = str_replace("[form-email]", $biz_field_email, $admin_email_text);
        $admin_email_text = str_replace("[first-field-label]", $biz_field_one, $admin_email_text);
        print $admin_email_text;
```